# MySQL query - Add string before, after existing data

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if someone is able to lend some wisdom about how to accomplish the following task in MySQL.

I need to run a query to add something inside a field before and after the existing data.  For example, let's say I have the following data in 'characters.name':

```
'Fred Flintstone'
'Barney Rubble'
```

How would I insert something, in this example 'xxxxx' before the existing data 'Fred Flinstone' and also 'yyyyy' after the data?

The result would be:

```
'xxxxxFred Flintstoneyyyyy'
'xxxxxBarney Rubbleyyyyy'
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 25):

```
SELECT CONCAT('xxxxx', name, 'yyyyy') AS name FROM characters
```

Comment: Or if you want to definitly change values in your database: `UPDATE characters SET name=CONCAT('xxxxx',name,'yyyyy') WHERE name='Fred Flinstone' OR name='Barney Rubbley'` (or without the where clause to change the value of `name` for all rows)